# XSLT concatenation of tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this sample document:

```
<root>
    <span class="a">te</span><span class="a">st</span> <span class="a">tag</span>
    some other text
    <span class="b">keep</span>
</root>
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
<root>
    <span class="a">test tag</span>
    some other text
    <span class="b">keep</span>
</root>
```

Or at least this:

```
<root>
    <span class="a">test</span> <span class="a">tag</span>
    some other text
    <span class="b">keep</span>
</root>
```

There will be variable count of `class="a"` spans.
Is it possible in XSLT?

**EDIT**

tried to solve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*/span[@class = 'a']"/>
    <xsl:template match="*/span[@class = 'a'][1]">
        <span class="a">
            <xsl:for-each select="../span[@class = 'a'] | ../text()[. = ' ']">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=". = ' '">
                        <xsl:copy/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but when I have this input?

```
<root>
    <span class="a">te</span><span class="a">st</span> <span class="a">tag</span>
    some other text
    <span class="b">keep</span>
    <span class="a">te</span><span class="a">st</span> <span class="a">tag</span>
</root>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: The answer is "Yes! It is possible". Can you say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 though? Thanks!

Comment: Till now I used XSLT 1.0 since there is no 2.0 support in python's lxml. I see, there is possibility of 2.0 through Java but I'm not using it now. If there is some program for Linux you could advice I'll be happy :-), but when there isn't I must stay on XSLT 1.0.

Comment: "*There will be variable count of class="a" spans.*" But will they always be adjacent, or separated by white-space only text nodes, as shown in your example? And what about other classes - are they supposed to be grouped together too?

Comment: I need only class="a" to be grouped together. And yes only adjacent (with optional whitespace separation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second variant can be achieved using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="grp" 
         match="span[@class='a'][preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::span[@class='a']]]" 
         use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::span[@class='a'][not(preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::span[@class='a']])][1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[@class='a'][not(preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::span[@class='a']])]" priority="1">
    <span class="a">
        <xsl:for-each select=". | key('grp', generate-id())" >
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[@class='a']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With some more work, you could include the interspersing white-space only text nodes in the group. Alternatively, look at a technique known as "sibling recursion".